# Can anyone identify this orchid?

Tags: identification, orchids, tropical

Can anyone identify this orchid? I found it growing in a mango tree. I am on the Tropical island of Trinidad in the West Indies, so Tropical rain-forest similar to the Amazon. My mother may have bought it and the birds distributed it, so I do not know if it is a native to this part of the world.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Palm like leaves and psudobulbs:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Catasetum or maybe Cycnoches - genera which are very similar.  It is not possible to determine the exact species without the flowers. Please see the helpful links below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catasetum

http://myorchidcare.com/orchid-care/Orchid-Identification.html

Comment: Agree.  Looks very much like a Catasetum.